# Report on build metrics

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

I need to report on build metrics. There is a plugin that offers this information called [build-metrics](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-metrics/) but it does not work with blue ocean.

Has anybody found a way to accomplish this?

I've tried using the [Jenkins CLI](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/) (version 2.361.2) to get this information. There are a lot of features built into the CLI but I can't figure out how to get the status of all builds that were run over a weekly time frame.